# Does Moqui framework has built in support for reporting tool like Jasper, Birt, Pentaho etc

Tags: reporting, birt, moqui

Does Moqui framework has built in support for reporting tool like Jasper, Birt, Pentaho etc, I searched the online documentation and could not find any information, What is the recommended tool for generating custom reports

Answer (score 1):

Moqui supports Report Builder and Custom Reports (Report Viewer) natively, and perhaps does not need integration with external Reporting Tools like Jasper, Birt and Pentaho for export to csv or JSON, and i believe other report types like pdf can be added with customization. The native Reports Builder and Custom Reports (Reports Viewer) are present in POPC ERP and HiveMind Admin for reference. Moqui native Reports Viewer supports .csv and Download JSON.

POPC > Report Builder > Edit Report screen
[image: POPC > Report Builder > Edit Report screen]

POPC ERP > Report Viewer (supports Exporting to Download JSON, CSV)
[image]